# Given Banach / normed space $X$ find $E$ such that $E^* = X$, where $^*$ denotes dual space.

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

The concept of the dual space is well known and in some cases computably up to an isometric isomorphism, i.e. $c_0^* \cong \ell_1$ or $\ell_p \cong \ell_q$.

What if we are given a space $X$ and want to find an space $E$ such that $E^* = X$ (or $\cong$)? What constrains do we have to put on $X$ to find such a space $E$?

Could this be a way to show that given $X$, it must be complete, since the dual space of a normed space is complete?

Comment: $c_0$ is itself complete but not a dual of a Banach space.

Comment: Re your point about using existence of a predual to verify completeness: If you find Cauchy sequences inelegant, then you might define: A normed space is Banach iff the canonical injection $X\to X^{**}$ has closed image.

Comment: I think, but cannot prove, that $C[0,1]$ in the sup-norm is not (isometrically isomorphic to) the dual of any Banach space.

Comment: An interesting neccesery condition is that $B_X$ must have extremal points (by Krein-Milman and Banach-Alaoglu theorems). You can use this to show that $L_1$ has no predual.

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets So there's a term for what I'm searching for and it's *predual*?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: The Krein-Milman argument suggested by KeeperOfSecrets also works to show $C[0,1]$ is not a dual, because the only extreme points of its ball are the constants $1$ and $-1$, and the ball is certainly not the closed convex hull of those.

Comment: You may be interested in the paper ["A note on dual Banach spaces" by Sten Kaijser, *Math. Scand.* 41 (1977), 325-330](https://www.mscand.dk/article/download/11725/9741)